# Mobile Push not Received

Tags: mobilepush-android

My Device has successfully completed registration using MobilePush SDK.
While creating message, I can see "OUTBOUND User Initiated". But Push is never received at my application.
When I try to trigger the push using Rest APi's, I can see that Token Id is generated, but push can not be received at my device.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation found [HERE](http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/journey-builder-for-apps/sdk-implementation/register-your-devices.html#android-androidstudio) and verify that you have 1) set the correct permissions, 2) included the manifest entries for our receivers and 3) included the manifest entries for our services.